# Bash processes with deleted link targets in /proc/<pid>/exe

Tags: linux, bash, process, c

We have a software which intercepts file IO operations and noticed a recent bug caused by a process who's `/proc/$pid/exe` pointed to `/usr/bin/bash;61f1808a (deleted)` (via readlink(2)). I'm curious what could be causing this and if the image `/usr/bin/bash;61f1808a` actually existed at some point or if there's a way to intentionally spawn processes with invalid images.

Relevant system is CentOS 7.9 with kernel 3.10, presumably bash 4.2.46 but of course would be nice to know if it happens on newer stuff too

Comment: Are containers involved on this system?

Comment: I believe that the host environment is windows but I think that the only virtualization is VMWare... asking the person who reported it

Comment: Can you post output of `cat /proc/$pid/cmdline` could be a shell script...

Comment: @MichaelD.no I'm sorry I can't this is associated with a bug report where the reporter did not provide steps to reproduce apart from "the app had been running for over 70 hrs"

Comment: performed in vmware, no containers, host is windows